# NSTextView string is null when calling from an other class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm a newbie in Cocoa
I have a function in a class call TextSaver.m :

```
- (void) save {
    TheNotes *myNote = [[TheNotes alloc]init];
    myNote.theText = [theTextView string];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNote.theText);
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myNote.theText toFile:@"..."];
}
```

And I'm calling it from the AppDelegate with applicationWillTerminate :

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [theTextSaver save];
}
```

But `NSLog(@"%@",myNote.theText);` results null... Like `NSLog(@"%@",theTextView);`. Which means when I call the function I can't access theTextView.
I've already try to call this function in the TextSaver.m class with a -(IBAction) and it worked!

Hope you can help me !

**EDIT**
The TextSaver is created with an `#import TextSaver.h` and in the appInterface 
`TextSaver *theTextSaver;`

**EDIT 2**
I rewrite the code to make it simpler :

AppDelegate.h :

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TheNotes.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    TheNotes *myNote;
}

@property (copy) TheNotes *myNote;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize myNote;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    myNote = [[TheNotes alloc]init]; //Do I need to put it in -(id) init ?
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [myNote save];
}

@end
```

TheNotes.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TheNotes : NSObject {
    NSString *theText;
    IBOutlet NSTextView *theTextView;// Do I need to alloc memory ?
}

-(void) save;
@property (copy) NSString *theText;

@end
```

TheNotes.m :

```
@implementation TheNotes
@synthesize theText;

- (void) save {
    NSLog(@"%@",theTextView.string);// Save is properly called, but this results (null).
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:theTextView.string toFile:@"..."];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'd be suspicious that the `TextSaver` object in your app delegate is not the same one that's on the screen.  How does `theTextSaver` get created/initialized?

Comment: @Starboard, just out of curiosity, does your app not support background execution? Or in what situation does `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification` get called? From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol.pdf), it will only be called when the app is terminated, however when I tested in the simulator, it was never called when I deleted the app.

Comment: Re: your edit....  `TextSaver *theTextSaver;` is just a declaration; it doesn't actually create anything...nor does a `#import`.

Comment: If you're going to make `theTextView` an outlet, then you should connect it to the text view in a nib. That's only possible if your TextSaver is created in or owns the same nib that the text view is in. Either way, you should not also create the text view in code; you will then be replacing one text view with another (one in the nib, one created in the code).

Comment: @PeterHosey theTextView is connected to the NSTextView in the nib, but I don't understand what you mean by "That's only possible if your TextSaver is created in or owns the same nib that the text view is in".

Comment: @Starboard: You can't connect an outlet across nibs. TextSaver needs to either be the File's Owner of the nib that the text view is in, or be an object in the same nib. If “theTextView is connected to the NSTextView in the nib”, that implies that you're already good to go on that front. That just leaves not creating the TextSaver in multiple places and thereby having more than one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The two questions you need to answer for yourself are:

- Why do I expect my TextSaver to know about the text view?
- Where do I tell the TextSaver about the text view?

The other possible answer to the first question is “the TextSaver created the text view”, but I'm assuming that's not the case.

So, you need to find where you think you're telling the TextSaver about the text view and make sure that's the case.

If you haven't done anything specific to tell the TextSaver about the text view, but rather are expecting it to just know about it, then that's probably the problem.

As Phillip Mills alluded to in his comment, merely declaring a variable named `theTextView` does not mean that the TextSaver knows about *the text view*. The compiler cannot read English: the names you choose are for your own benefit only; the compiler treats them only as identifiers. It does not see “theTextView” and go “oh, that! that's over there; I'll go get it”.

In order for `theTextView` to actually point to *the text view*, you need to put the text view there. You do this via assignment. Either expose `theTextView` as a property and set it from somewhere else, or set it internally within the TextSaver class (after either creating the text view yourself or getting it from another object).

I would make it a property (named simply `textView`) and set that property from whatever owns both the TextSaver and the text view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of basically what you're trying to achieve, HTH.

There are two classes, AppDelegate and TestViewController. TestViewController has a UITextView, whenever the user presses the home button of the device while editing the UITextView, the `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method of the AppDelegate is called and the note is printed to the console (here you could save the note instead).

I use `applicationDidEnterBackground` because it's what is called when the app goes into background mode.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    PVSTestViewController *nextScreen = [[PVSTestViewController alloc] init];
    self.delegate = nextScreen;      // Assign TestViewController as the AppDelegate's delegate.
    self.window.rootViewController = nextScreen;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.delegate saveData]; // Called when the user presses the home button.
}
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
....

@protocol PVSAppDelegateProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)saveData;     // Any class that conforms to our protocol must implement this method.

@end

@interface PVSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PVSAppDelegateProtocol> delegate;   // Here we store the delegate class.

@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
#import "PVSTestViewController.h"

@interface PVSTestViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation PVSTestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)saveData
{
    // This is called by the AppDelegate when the app goes into the background.
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text is: %@", self.textView.text ]);
}

@end
```

**TestViewController.h**

```
....

#import "PVSAppDelegate.h"

@interface PVSTestViewController : UIViewController <PVSAppDelegateProtocol>

@end
```